# BioPython consensus sequence with gaps coded as 'N' and polymorphisms as ambiguities

Tags: alignment, ambiguity, biopython, consensus

I am trying to write code to get a consensus sequence for each of the 100+ files of individual fasta alignments in a folder. To start I just wanted to get the consensus for one sequence (then I will use a for loop to process all), but I am having trouble with the alphabet of the consensus.  My test fasta alignment is:

```
>seq1
ACGTACGATCGTTACTCCTA
>seq2
ACGTACGA---TTACTCGTA
```

and what I want the consensus to look like is:

```
ACGTACGANNNTTACTCSTA
```

I would like any column that contains a gap to be represented by 'N' and any column without 100% identical nucleotides to be represented by ambiguity codes.

My code that doesn't work is:

```
from Bio import AlignIO
from Bio.Align import AlignInfo
from Bio.Alphabet import IUPAC, Gapped
alphabet = Gapped(IUPAC.ambiguous_dna)

alignment = AlignIO.read(open("fasta_align_for_consensus.fa"), "fasta")
summary_align = AlignInfo.SummaryInfo(alignment)
consensus = summary_align.gap_consensus(threshold = 1.0, ambiguous = 'N', consensus_alpha  \
= alphabet, require_multiple = 2)
```

The object 'ambiguous' only takes a string and places an 'N' in any place in the consensus where there is a polymorphism in the alignment, which I can't seem to work around.  Any suggestion on how to correct this would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The current simple consensus methods don't do what you want. It sounds like you're asking IUPAC ambiguity codes (perhaps with some threshold?) and special treatment of gaps. You'd have to write some code yourself, perhaps based on the existing methods.

Comment: Thanks for your response Peter.